# When do we have $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}<+\infty$ for $r>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $r>0$ and
>   $$
> a_n(r)=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}
> $$ When do we have
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(r)<+\infty?
> $$

---

One can write
$$
a_n(r)=\frac1n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^r}
$$
which looks simpler but I don't see how it would help. Also I tried to bounded $\{a_n(r)\}$ but I don't see how.

[ADDED:](Thanks to Daniel) It does look like a Riemann sum. I think this is not an integral on a finite integral. Instead it looks like $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^r}dx.$$ But I'm not sure if this the corresponding integral or not.

Comment: If you look at it as a Riemann sum, you get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $a_n(r)$ is a Riemann sum for

$$\int_0^n \frac{dx}{1+x^r}.$$

The upper limit of the integration depends on $n$, but that is not much of a problem. Since $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^r}$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, we have

$$a_n(r) < \int_0^n \frac{dx}{1+x^r},$$

and for $r > 1$, we have $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx < \infty$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n(r) < \infty$ (assuming the existence of the limit for the moment).

On the other hand,

$$a_n(r) > \int_{1/n}^{n+1/n} \frac{dx}{1+x^r}$$

again by the monotonicity of $f$, so we see that for $r \leqslant 1$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n(r) = \infty$. But for $r > 1$ this estimate also shows the existence of the limit that was only assumed above.

Comment: I don't see how $a_n(r)>\int_{1/n}^{n+1/n}\frac{dx}{1+x^r}$

Comment: Because for every $k$, we have $$\frac1n\cdot \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^r} = \frac1n\cdot f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) > \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x)\,dx$$ by the monotonicity of $f$.